# How to fix a date returned as 1970-01-01?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search result between two date of one column and I convert date into y-m-d formate but I get response 1970-01-01, what can I do?

```
$dToDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aData['to_date']))." 00:00:01";

    $dFromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aData['from_date']))." 23:59:59";


    $sAndWhere  = "1 = 1";
    $sAndWhere .= " AND d.created_at between '".$dToDate.' AND '.$dFromDate."'";
    $sAndWhere .= " AND u.mood =".$sMood;

    $sAndWhere .= " AND d.activated = 1 AND d.deleted=0";
    $sSql = "SELECT 
                *
            FROM 
                diaries d
            LEFT JOIN 
                users u 
            ON 
              d.id_user = u.id_user
            WHERE ".$sAndWhere;
```

Comment: First of all echo your date and check is empty or not.

Comment: Maybe $aData['to_date']) or $aData['from_date'] is empty. Please check it.

Comment: Yes i get which i put.

Comment: Show your date in your question.

Comment: @NikhilVaghla thank you for your reply its my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dToDate = $dFromDate = "";
if(strtotime($aData['to_date']) > 0)
{
    $dToDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aData['to_date']))." 00:00:01";
}

if(strtotime($aData['from_date']) > 0)
{
    $dFromDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aData['from_date']))." 23:59:59";
}

$sAndWhere  = "1 = 1";
if(($dToDate != "")  && ($dFromDate!=""))
{
    $sAndWhere .= " AND d.created_at between '".$dToDate."' AND '".$dFromDate."'";
}
else if($dToDate != "")
{
    $sAndWhere .= " AND d.created_at = '".$dToDate."'";
}
else if($dFromDate != "")
{
    $sAndWhere .= " AND d.created_at = '".$dFromDate."'";
}
$sAndWhere .= " AND u.mood =".$sMood;

$sAndWhere .= " AND d.activated = 1 AND d.deleted=0";
$sSql = "SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            diaries d
        LEFT JOIN 
            users u 
        ON 
          d.id_user = u.id_user
        WHERE ".$sAndWhere;
```

use this code

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!